# How can I calculate the U,V texture coordinates on a disk at infinity given only a view vector and a vector pointing to the disk's center?

Tags: raytracing

I'm using an approach similar to [Bruneton's paper on atmospheric scattering](http://www-ljk.imag.fr/Publications/Basilic/com.lmc.publi.PUBLI_Article@11e7cdda2f7_f64b69/article.pdf) for rendering my sky and am trying to extend it to add a textured moon.

Long story short, the paper works by essentially inverting a screen pixel to a world-space vector, then effectively raytracing the sky. To draw the sun, the paper checks the dot product between the sun-vector and pixel view-vector, and gives a "yes hit" or "no not hit" 1 or 0 based on a step function and the angular size of the sun. All of these vectors are unit.

Similarly, I'm doing the same thing to determine if there's a hit on the moon, however unlike the sun, I also now need to determine a texture coordinate. At first I simply subtracted the view vector from the moon vector, normalized the result, then scaled it by the angle between the view and moon vectors. This gives me the correct world-space point, but I'm having a hard time converting this 3-D world space point to a U,V texture coordinate on the intersected moon-disk.

A graphic to illustrate my problem:

[image]

My question is this:
**Given two unit vectors, how can I calculate a texture coordinate of a point formed by the angle between them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dot product function, pseudo-code:

```
vector2 texcoord;

texcoord.x = DotProduct(i1, right) * 0.5 + 0.5;
texcoord.y = DotProduct(i1, up) * 0.5 + 0.5;
```

Where up is a normalized vector pointing at the direction you want for up in your disc / texture.
Similarly for right.

i1 should be scaled to match the radius of your disc at unit length. So that i1 will be of unit length when reaching the edge of the disc.

The dot products will give you values between -1 and 1 within the rectangle (texture) area that bounds your disc, larger values beyond it.

The `* 0.5 + 0.5` is there to center the coordinates into your texture so they range from 0 to 1 instead of -1 to 1.

[image]