# Projecting a moon texture to the background

Tags: textures, raytracing

I want to display a 2d moon image to the background. I have a normalized direction for the center location of my moon texture. I also have the normalized view direction from the camera for each pixel. I'm working in HLSL and I need to find the uv for the texture. How can I do this without the texture being distorted. I tried a variety of spherical uv mapping equations but none of them worked. 
This post works but only if d is (0,0,1) in a right handed Y up coordinate system:
[How can I calculate the U,V texture coordinates on a disk at infinity given only a view vector and a vector pointing to the disk's center?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113666/how-can-i-calculate-the-u-v-texture-coordinates-on-a-disk-at-infinity-given-only)
It seems like you have to rotate the up righting right vectors with moon's location but how?

Comment: You say texture, that implies you are talking about a square, why are you talking about a disk?  Also if you want fixed size view, just draw the moon first, then draw everything else, never change the moons translation...

Comment: The disk is form by the intersection of the square texture and the sphere. It should be the same size as the moon on the texture. I need to be able to move the moon around for a day/night cycle.